# Why does clicking on my search button return an error?

Tags: javascript, testing, loadrunner

I am using true client protocol and I have a web app with a search button implemented using an Image. I click on that image button to extract some results.

html code of Search button is:

```
< img style="border: medium none;" 
onclick="ajaxLoadingStarted(this, document.getElementById('select:ajaxLoadingImg')); searchVehicles();" 
src="/webPortal/common/images/green-search-btn.png" id="select:searchBtn">
```

and my javascript code is:

```
var searchobj = document.getElementById('select:searchBtn').onclick();
```

Unfortunately, I got this error:

> t=00019690ms: Error -203252: 46: Evaluate JavaScript code /
>   window.alert($('#javax.face...ement; } } / failed - exception occured:
>   NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available [MsgId:
>   MERR-203252]

Why might this be happening?

Comment: It did not give any error to me. http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/C6mXH/  - Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 3.6.3 using ajax true client on LR 11.03

Comment: anyone got an idea about clicking an image thru javascripting??

Answer (score 0):

Certain functionality is not available if you play an individual step instead of playing the script from the start. An alternative would be to create a breakpoint on the step after the one you are trying, and play the entire script from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced similar issue while scripting.The solution would be:

1. Use Ajax Click and Script  protocol to record it.
2. If it is still not recognized then use the following code:

```
web_text_link("", 
    "Snapshot=t50.inf", 
    DESCRIPTION, 
    "Text="",
    "ID=select:searchBtn", 
    ACTION, 
    "UserAction=Click", 
LAST);
```